# How to get the low and high of the chart window in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot something that is sometimes far away from the current price, therefore, it shrinks my chart. So I figured maybe I will limit the parameter to the low/high the chart shown in the chart window, but cannot get this low/high value.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the chart's visible on screen range or exact amount of candles.
However you toggle the `Scale Price Chart Only` option in the scale's properties, this way it will be scaled only with candle's range.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a semi-solution since I want to see that there is something far away, but at least my chart stays nice.